# Is there a possibility to set the formatting of specific tags and its content to one single line in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, epub

**User Story**

I would like the formatter of VSC to format every `<navPoint>` and its content into one single line to achieve easier overview and editing possibilities.

---

**Generalized Question**

Is there a possibility to set the formatting of specific tags and its content to one single line in Visual Studio Code?

---

**Background Details**

In an `epub` container there is an xml file with `ncx` extension, which documents the `playOrder` of html files in the EPUB container.

Often I have to check this `playOrder` or – in case of a validation errors – I need to correct the `playOrder` values manually.

Since I like to use the multiline editing feature of VSC, I have to delete all the line breaks exept the ones before `<navPoint>`.

Therefore I delete all the tabs/whitespaces at line beginnings with `^( )+` and use `\n(?!<navPoint)` (note the missing `>`, since navpoints have properties) to delete all the line breaks I don’t need.

After this editing I am able to have a quicker overview of possible mistakes and may edit the `playOrder` values much faster with multiline editing and the [incrementor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nmsmith89.incrementor) plugin.

But is there a faster/btter way to achieve the *after editing* result in VSC?

---

Before editing:

```xml
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="1" id="cover">
    <navLabel>
        <text>Cover</text>
    </navLabel>
    <content src="sections/cover.xhtml" />
</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="2" id="titlepage">
    <navLabel>
        <text>Title</text>
    </navLabel>
    <content src="sections/titlepage.xhtml" />
</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="3" id="copyright">
    <navLabel>
        <text>Copyright</text>
    </navLabel>
    <content src="sections/copyright.xhtml" />
</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="4" id="contents">
    <navLabel>
        <text>Contents</text>
    </navLabel>
    <content src="sections/contents.xhtml" />
</navPoint>
…
```

After editing:

```xml
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="1" id="cover" >…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="2" id="titlepage">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="3" id="copyright">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="4" id="contents">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="5" id="section1">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="6" id="section2">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="7" id="section3">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="8" id="section4">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="9" id="section5">…</navPoint>
<navPoint class="document" playOrder="10" id="section6">…</navPoint>
…
```

Comment: how do you handle `navPoint` tag inside `navPoint` tag (sub sections of chapters)

Answer (score 2):

You could use an extension like [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules) to run multiple regex find/replaces on text.  In your settings.json:

```json
"replacerules.rules": {  
  "Strip newlines in navPoint element": {
    "find": "\n(?!<navPoint)",
    "replace": ""
  },
    
  "Strip whitespace between elements": {
    "find": "^( )+",
    "replace": ""
  }
},
    
"replacerules.rulesets": {
  "Unindent navPoint element and content": {
    "rules": [
      "Strip whitespace between elements",
      "Strip newlines in navPoint element"
    ]
  }
}
```

and a keybinding to trigger that (in keybindings.json):

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+]",             // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "replacerules.runRuleset",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.ncx/",
  "args": {
      "rulesetName": "Unindent navPoint element and content"
  }
}
```

First Select what you want to change and then your chosen keybinding:

[image: strip navPoint newlines and whitespace]

Comment: Great! It works as described. Thank you for this solution, [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836330/mark).